# GKE is built by default in Anthos solution ? Getting Anthos Metrics

Tags: kubernetes, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, google-anthos

I have a cluster with 7 nodes and a lot of services, nodes, etc in the Google Cloud Platform. I'm trying to get some metrics with StackDriver Legacy, so in the Google Cloud Console -> StackDriver -> Metrics Explorer I have all the set of anthos metrics listed but when I try to create a chart based on that metrics it doesn't show the data, actually the only response that I get in the panel is `no data is available for the selected time frame` even changing the time frame and stuffs.

Is right to think that with anthos metrics I can retrieve information about my cronjobs, pods, services like failed initializations, jobs failures ? And if so, I can do it with StackDriver Legacy or I need to Update to StackDriver kubernetes Engine Monitoring ?

Answer (score 3):

Anthos solution, includes what’s called [GKE-on prem](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/overview). I’d take a look at the instructions to use logging and [monitoring on GKE-on prem](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/how-to/administration/logging-and-monitoring). Stackdriver monitors GKE On-Prem clusters in a similar way as cloud-based GKE clusters.

However, there’s [a note](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/concepts/logging-and-monitoring#logging_and_monitoring) where they say that currently, Stackdriver only collects cluster logs and system component metrics. The full Kubernetes Monitoring experience will be available in a future release.

You can also check that you’ve met all the [configuration requirements](https://cloud.google.com/gke-on-prem/docs/concepts/logging-and-monitoring#stackdriver_requirements.).